# Mysql использование update в запросе

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет.
Пытаюсь обновить оптовую цену товаров, которые были проданы больше 20 раз, но в результате сталкиваюсь с ошибкой

> operand should contain 1 column(s)

Направьте в нужное русло.
Прикладываю структуры таблиц, вдруг понадобятся

[image: Таблица zakaz]
[image: Таблица tovary]

```
UPDATE tovary SET cenaopt = cenaopt*0.1
WHERE
(select nametov, cenaopt 
from tovary t, zakaz z
where 
t.id_tov = z.id_tov AND z.zakazano>20);
```

Comment: в строчке `z.zakazano>20` пробовали ставить пробелы? т.к. может быть из-за знака "больше" операнд не определяется: `z.zakazano > 20`

Comment: @KrasPvP,
Да, пробовал, все та же ошибка

Comment: второй WHERE капсом писали? sql, на сколько помню, регистрозависимый

Comment: @KrasPvP, Регистрозависимости не наблюдал, писал до этого запросы и верхним и нижним регистром, все работало. Попробовал написать where нижним регистром, ничего не изменилось, ошибка сохраняется

Comment: Многотабличный UPDATE в MySQL отличается от такового в других диалектах отсутствием двойной FROM. В показанном запросе в `UPDATE tovary` и в `from tovary` - две совершенно разные копии таблицы, хотя логика требует,чтобы она была одна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE tovary t, zakaz z 
SET t.cenaopt = t.cenaopt * 0.1
WHERE t.id_tov = z.id_tov 
  AND z.zakazano > 20;
```

Правда, снижение оптовой цены вотпрям аж в десять раз... чёта тут не то.

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли. Вы правы, пропустил cenaopt+cenaopt*0.1

Comment: тогда можно было и `*1.1`